# How to pass a function literal as a callback

Tags: d

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
void x(function int(int) f){
    f(555);
}

void main(){
    x(function int(int q){  });
}
```

The error messages are confusing:

```
funcs.d(4): Error: basic type expected, not function
funcs.d(4): Error: found 'int' when expecting '('
funcs.d(4): Error: basic type expected, not (
funcs.d(4): Error: function declaration without return type. (Note that constructors are always named 'this')
funcs.d(4): Error: found 'f' when expecting ')'
```

I cannot get anything from such error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap the return type with the `function` keyword in `x`. For some reason they are the other way around on literals. Also, the function you pass does not return anything even though it should

```
void x(int function(int) f){
    f(555);
}

void main(){
    x((int q){ return 0; });
    // or
    x(function int(int q){ return 0; });
    // or
    x(q => 0);
}
```